# Make text like "Tags section" in Stack overflow

Tags: jquery, css

I want to make text like  "tags section" in stack over flow "Ask Question" Section. Screen Shot is attached below.
[image]
How can I achieve this?

**Explanation.**
I have text box which populate the text box through ajax i want the populated text box to show like a bubble with cross mark over to remove it. how can I achive this as currently whole text box disappear on text box click. below is the screen shot.

Comment: Did you try anything? Please post a complete example in your question.

Comment: You can do that by third party library. [Jquery Tags Input](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BOOTSTRAP to get the same

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body> 
 
<div class="container">
  <h5>Example <span class="label label-default">New<span>&nbsp;&times;</span></span></h5>
</div>

</body>
```

And change the color as you need.

Comment: You have to make a function to hide that on the click of cross symbol

Comment: and you can use jquery for that.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#t').click(function () {
            var div = document.getElementById('tes');
            div.style.display = div.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
            return false;
        });

    </script>

Comment: <h5 id="tes" runat="server">Example <span class="label label-default">New<span id="t" runat="server">&nbsp;&times;</span></span></h5>

Comment: I added above script mentioned in comment but its not working

Comment: Check the below answer its hiding it

Comment: please specify more

Comment: I have a text box which shows text through ajax i want to show this text as bubble with cross sign above the text so when i click the cross sign text should be removed

Comment: Please check the second answer given by me and check if its what you need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173465/discussion-between-adesh-kumar-and-raja).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </head>
    <body> 
     
    <div class="container">
      <h5>Example <span class="label label-default">New<span class="closeIt" style="cursor:pointer;">&nbsp;&times;</span></span></h5>
      <h5>Example <span class="label label-default">New1<span class="closeIt" style="cursor:pointer;">&nbsp;&times;</span></span></h5>
      <h5>Example <span class="label label-default">New2<span class="closeIt" style="cursor:pointer;">&nbsp;&times;</span></span></h5>
    </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.closeIt').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});
</script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Have a look at this

Comment: if it's not what you need please let me know.

Comment: it remove the whole text box when i click on text box. I have edited my question please check out

Comment: can I see your code as I am not able to understand what textbox you are talking about? As we have only small badges no textbox

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50944327/make-text-like-tags-section-as-used-in-stack-overflow

Comment: this is link of question please see this